# Where can I ask help for Windows dmp files?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, superuser

I am having some issues with a Windows machine due to a *["Video Scheduler Internal Error"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-bsod-video-scheduler-internal-error/9c7e98ea-43db-47ef-85c3-8e2898dcb018)* and after reading the appropriate `.dmp` file, I am not sure what a lot of it means. Where should I ask about interpreting the dmp file? Is it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) or is this more of a Microsoft support question?

Comment: Here's a hint: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22.dmp%22+Microsoft - try the cross-site search for suggestions, and each site's meta and help for what's on-topic.

Comment: What is more helpful then a binary .dmp file that has to be processed by somebody from the community is the windbg output analysis itself. That sort of question would be within scope at Super User.